# How to get child simple Product Obj from configurable Sales Order Items

Tags: magento-1.9, order-items

I want to get Configurable child simple products from order items.How can I get child simple Product from the configurable product? 
**I want to fetch only simple product object which associated with configurable product in order items**

Here is my code.I can not fetch together configurable product Id and its associated child simple product object.

```
echo "<pre>";
$items = $order->getAllItems();
foreach($items as $item){
print_r($item->getProduct());
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `$order->getAllVisibleItems()` instead of `$order->getAllItems()`

**Updated Answer**

`$order->getAllVisibleItems()` will return only configurable product.
Then you can get the child items of configurable products using `$item->getChildrenItems()`. This method (`getChildrenItems()`) is defined in `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item`. So, the code will be

```
foreach($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
$childItems = $item->getChildrenItems();
echo "<pre>";
   foreach($item->getChildrenItems() as $item){
     echo $item->getProduct()->getId(); // child product Id
     print_r($item->getProduct()); // child product Object
   }
 }
```

Comment: I want to get configurable item id and its associated simple product obj at same time

Comment: getAllVisibleItems() not return simple product which has a parent item

Comment: I want to get associated child product with configurable product and  $order->getAllVisibleItems() not return which has a parent item.

Comment: @NirajPatel Answer updated